# Transition not working in first creation of Diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I create a `D3` diagram like so

http://jsfiddle.net/gs6rehnx/2042/

```
<button type="button" onclick="createPie()">Click Me First!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="updatePie()">Update Diagram!</button>
<div class='foo'></div>


const width = 260;
const height = 260;
const thickness = 40;
const duration = 750;

const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - thickness)
  .outerRadius(radius);

const pie = d3
  .pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .sort(null);


const create = function(data) {
  const svg = d3
    .select('.foo')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'pie')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')
    .attr('id', 'bar');

  draw(data);
}

const draw = function(data) {
  const path = d3.select('#bar')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))

  path
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d, i) => color(i));

  path
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate({
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 0
      }, d);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    });
};


const data = [{
    name: 'USA',
    value: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'UK',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Canada',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Maxico',
    value: 40
  }
]

function createPie() {
  create(data)
}

const newData = [{
    name: 'USA',
    value: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'UK',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Canada',
    value: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'Maxico',
    value: 10
  }
];

function updatePie() {
  draw(newData)
}
```

On clicking the `Click Me First!` button, the diagram simply appears. When I click the `Update Diagram!` button, the transition works. Why isn't it working when clicking the first button?

Comment: usually trasnsition works when the element exists. So when you update, the diagram already exists so it has somewhere to transition from, but on first load, the diagram doesn't exist so it has nothing to transition from. I recommend when you first load the application load it in a certain state (like opacity 0) and then after that you add the class that changes that state (like opacity 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply,
when you click the `Click Me First`, make svg named bar in `create` function and call `draw`

but `Update Diagram!` click first button, svg doesn't exist.
so function `draw` is not working.

```
 const path = d3.select('#bar')
               .selectAll('path')
                .data(pie(data))
```